# What is "velocity of the boundary" in this Evan's PDE book?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Consider a family of smooth, boundary regions $U(\tau)\subset
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ that depend smoothly upon the parameter
> $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$. Write $v$ for the velocity of the moving boundary
> $dU(\tau)$ and $\nu $ for the outward pointing unit normal.
>
> If $f=f(x,\tau)$ is a smooth function, then
> $\frac{d}{d\tau}\int_{U(\tau)} fdx=\int_{\partial U(\tau)}fv\cdot\nu
>  dS+\int_{U(\tau)}f_\tau dx$.

How is "velocity of the moving boundary" defined? Plus, can you explain the intuition of the formula in words ? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the velocity of the boundary here to be a vector field.  Pick a point $x_0\in U(\tau_0)$, then consider the quantity
$$\varphi(\tau)=\frac{U(\tau+\tau_0)-U(\tau_0)}{\tau}$$
$\varphi$ is smooth by assumption so we can take a limit and interpret this as a vector field defined on the boundary of $U(\tau)$.  It carries with it information about how the point $x_0$ will evolve with $\tau$. As for the formula, I am not entirely sure what he means by $dU(\tau)$, I think it's supposed to be the manifolds map between tangent spaces.  You can think of $U$ as a map between manifolds I suppose.  Anyway, I think the intuition is that two contributions will cause a change in the value of the integral: the changes in $U$ and the changes in $f$.  The first integral is integrating the flux of the vector field $f\vec{v}$ where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of $U$ like we discussed.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @jk001 should have written $\partial U(\tau)$ instead of $dU(\tau)$. It's the boundary.

Comment: that makes sense.  If you are familiar with electromagnetics in physics, this is like the continuity equation for current and charge density.  The flux is like current and the function the charge density.

Comment: Yes, it's a boundary. Sorry about that. I'm not still sure why the "correction term" on the RHS should look like that. Any insights?

Comment: @jk001 are you referring to the surface integral?

Comment: @Nick Castillo Yes, that's what I meant!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it has to be flux of $fv$ and about the meaning of it. And does it have to be independent of the chosen point?

Comment: @jk001 the quantity $fv$ represents the 'current' of the function $f$.  Meaning, whatever units $f$ is givensay [units/$L^n$], $fv$ (which is a vector) will now have units of [units/$L^{n-1}\cdot$sec].  This quantity will be integrated over the surface measure of $\partial U(\tau)$ to produce the  a quantity with units [units/sec].

Comment: In the above $L$ is the unit of length

Comment: @Nick Castillo Never came across to me that way. Appreciate it!